# AWS Lambda Node.js 6.10 : "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'cfn-response'",

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a lambda function in Nodejs 6.10 and I am getting this error:

```
Response: 
{
    "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'cfn-response'",
    "errorType": "Error", 
    "stackTrace": [
       "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
       "require (internal/module.js:20:19)", 
       "Object. (/var/task/index.js:2:20)", 
       "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)", 
       "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
       "Module.load (module.js:487:32)", 
       "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
       "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)" 
    ]
}

Function Logs:

START RequestId: d1123bc9-1722-11e8-84a2-c9cba9c66de8 Version: $LATEST

Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:2:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
END RequestId: d1123bc9-1722-11e8-84a2-c9cba9c66de8
REPORT RequestId: d1123bc9-1722-11e8-84a2-c9cba9c66de8  Duration: 87.34 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB
```

I am using Node.js 6.10 version for this method and did inline code edit.

Code I am trying to execute:

```
var response = require('cfn-response');
  exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var input = parseInt(event.ResourceProperties.Input);
    var responseData = {Value: input * 5};
    response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData);
  };
```

Any clues?

Comment: Did you add `cfn-response` to the `package.json`?

Comment: No. I am deploying the code as part of CloudFormation's custom resource. So I can only specify the code inline.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is because of the way zipping the files making the problem. Instead of zipping the root folder you have to select all files and zip it like below,

Please upload all files and subfolders like below. Please include node_modules folder as well in the zip.

[image]

Comment: Did you include node_modules folder as well?

Comment: No. I am deploying the code as part of cloudformation's custom resource. So I can only specify the code inline.